# How to hide python pyc files in Windows Explorer?

Tags: python, windows, windows-vista

Is it possible to hide files with a certain extension? I'm using Windows Vista and don't want to see pyc files in the Windows file explorer. It would be nice to reduce the clutter. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy, and not depend on your python file or not.

Open command prompt, type the disk letter that you want to hide all `pyc` file. For example, type `D:`. and you will see command prompt will move to D drive.

After that, type this line:

```
attrib +h *.pyc /s
```

if you want to view again those file:

```
attrib -h *.pyc /s
```

if you don't want to hide all pyc file in all drive, after you move to one drive, you can use `cd` command to move into folder you like and type above command. For example:

```
cd Project/Python Project/Toy Project
```

You can replace pyc in above command with any file type you want. And, you must turn off "Show hidden file and folder" in `Folder Option`. If not, I'm pretty sure that no trick will help you.

Hope this help :)

Comment: I was hoping for a way of hiding them without having to disable "Show hidden file and folder"... is there a way I can unhide everything except *.pyc files?

Answer (score 2):

I stick this in my main python project file

```
import os
os.system('attrib +H *.pyc /S')
```

That hides the complied files everytime I run it and the directory stays nice and clean